# Proof about interpolation form of Lagrange.

Tags: linear-algebra, lagrange-interpolation

Prove all polynomials $p\in V$ is written of the form:
$p=\sum_{i=0}^n L_ip(a_i)$ where $L_i(x)=\prod_{j\not=i}\frac{x-a_j}{a_i-a_j}$ and $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ with $1\leq i\leq n$.

My work:

for each $i$ consider 
$L_i(x)=\prod_{j\not=i}\frac{x-a_j}{a_i-a_j}$

If $x=a_j$ with $j\not=i$ then $L_i(x)=\prod_{j\not=i}\frac{x-a_j}{a_i-a_j}=0$

Moreover,

If $x=a_j$ with $j=i$ then $L_i(x)=\prod_{j\not=i}\frac{x-a_j}{a_i-a_j}=1$

Then,

$\sum_{i=0}^n L_i(a_j)p(a_i)=\sum_{i=0}^n \delta_{ij}p(a_i)=p(a_j)$

In consequence,

$p=\sum_{i=0}^n L_ip(a_i)$

**Is good the proof? Is convicent?**

Comment: You showed that $p(a_i)=p(a_i)$, so to speak: the polynomial you created gives the output you wanted for all your test values. But there are many other polynomials that do that as well: just add any multiple of $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\ldots(x-a_n)$. Why is your polynomial the correct one?

Comment: @BobJones i take that polynomial for the Delta of Kronecker, because $L_i(a_j)=\delta_{ij}$ But, i dont not follow your argument, you say i need take $L_i(x-a_1), L_i(x-a_2)....$ etc?

Comment: @BobJones Can you give me more details? Thanks!

Comment: If I want a polynomial $p(x)$ with $p(0)=1$ and $p(1)=2$, the easiest one is $x+1$, but there are infinitely many others: $x^n+1$ for any integer $n$, for starters. Why is your polynomial the one you want?

Comment: If $q = \sum L_i p(a_ï)$, you proved that $p(a_j) = q(a_j)$, but you need to prove that $\forall x, p(x) = q(x)$. There is a missing argument. There is also a missing hypothesis on the degree of $p$ for this to work, or perhaps you should tell us what $V$ is?

Comment: @Gribouillis $V=\mathbb{R}_n[x]$ you have reason about that.

Comment: i want a $p \in \mathbb{R}_n[x]$ then you say i need prove for all point. x, no one unique point. true?

Comment: @BobJones i want the unicity of my polynomial?

Comment: If $n=2$ and $p(x)=x^2+1$, you get the formula $p(x)=x+1$ by plugging in. This is false.

Comment: @BobJones When $n=2$, the polynomial has degree 2 but there are $n+1=3$ points $a_i$. The trick is to remark that $p(x) - q(x)$ has degree $\le n$ and has at least $n+1$ distinct roots.

Comment: @Gribouillis Yes I understand. I'm telling Bvss12 that his statement from the beginning is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Gribouillis i go to think the proof again. Really in this moment i don't know how to prove that.